# Count values from same date and print the count in front of the date in a new table

Tags: excel, vba

I want to count the values from 1 sheet which is updated everyday and print the number of count on day basis in another sheet without having to set the start and end date

Answer (score 0):

Would you please let us know, do the sheets contain a column of dates?

Does the daily updated sheet contain many dates?

Excel formula

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,TODAY())
```

VBA Macro

```
Sub test()
Range("A1").Formula = "=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,TODAY())"
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it does have

Comment: From sheet 1 to sheet 2 and yes the dates are being updated everyday, column c is dedicated for this date